# CodedUI Keyboard.SendKeys() sends Keys Randomly

Tags: coded-ui-tests

This was always working up until now...

I am testing a web Application and need to enter Users Name into HTMLEDIT control

```
KeyBoard.SendKeys(control,"Alice");
```

this enters Name as **"AAAicce"**

I am using VS2013,This was working fine with VS2010.

Please suggest what is going wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

It happens when control is not in Focus. You can try clicking on control and then sending keys to make sure it goes to right control.

Comment: I've noticed that when I pause the debugger right before this line and then step into it or resume, I experience the same thing.  It's a pain to say the least.  Setting the focus does help, though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the delay? For example:

```
Keyboard.SendKeysDelay = 1000; // 1-second delay between keystrokes
```

Comment: Yes I set Delay but the same charecters are sent with delay of 1 sec- "AAAicce"